# SQL Server 2008 R2: Prepare dynamic temporary VIEW

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures, sql-server-2008-r2

**Table's**:

```
CREATE TABLE Test_01
(
    Cola VARCHAR(MAX),
    Colb VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO Test_01 VALUES(1,'A');

CREATE TABLE Test_02
(
    Cola VARCHAR(MAX),
    Colb VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO Test_02 VALUES(2,'B');

CREATE TABLE Test_03
(
    Cola VARCHAR(MAX),
    Colb VARCHAR(MAX)
);

INSERT INTO Test_01 VALUES(3,'C');
```

**View**:

```
CREATE VIEW View_Test AS 
SELECT * FROM Test_01 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Test_02 UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM Test_03 UNION ALL;
```

**Records**:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.View_test

Cola        Colb
------------------
1       A
2       B
3       C
```

**Note**: Now I want to prepare a temporary view by passing `Cola` values to the store procedure.

**Example**: If I pass Value `1` to the stored procedure then it should prepare a temporary view
with the table `test_01` because record `1` belongs to table `test_01`.

If I pass Value `1,2,3` to the stored procedure then it should prepare a temporary view
with the table's `test_01,test_02,test_03` because record `1,2,3` belongs to table `test_01,test_02,test_03`.

For above requirement I have written the following stored procedure:

**Stored Procedure**:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE sp_Test_90
@Cola varchar(MAX)

AS

DECLARE @SQL VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Tab VARCHAR(MAX)
DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(MAX)

    DECLARE Cur CURSOR FAST_FORWARD FOR 
    SELECT TABLE_NAME FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.VIEW_TABLE_USAGE
    WHERE VIEW_NAME = 'View_Test'

    OPEN Cur 
    FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Tab
    WHILE(@@FETCH_STATUS=0)
    BEGIN

        IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#Temp') IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
                DROP TABLE #Temp
        END

        CREATE TABLE #Temp
        (
            ColaValues VARCHAR(MAX)
        );

        SET @SQL = 'INSERT INTO #Temp(ColaValues) SELECT DISTINCT Cola FROM ['+@Tab+'] WHERE Cola IN('''+REPLACE(@Cola,',',''',''')+''')';
        PRINT(@SQL);
        EXECUTE(@SQL);

        ----------------------
        /*Got Stuck HERE*/
        ----------------------
        IF (SELECT DISTINCT colavalues FROM #Temp)  IN(''''+REPLACE(@Cola,',',''',''')+'''')---IN (@Cola) -------GOT STUCK HERE
        BEGIN

            SET @SQL +='SELECT * FROM ['+@Tab+'] UNION ALL';

        END
        FETCH NEXT FROM Cur INTO @Tab

    END

    CLOSE Cur;

    DEALLOCATE Cur;

    SET @Query = 'WITH CTE
              AS
                          (
                              '+@SQL+'
              ) 
                          SELECT * FROM CTE';

    PRINT(@Query);
    EXECUTE(@Query);

GO
```

But got stuck in the if condition to check whether Cola value present in the given parameter or not.

Comment: The idea of "temporary view" is really unclear. Can you tell us what you mean by that and the purpose of it?

Comment: Side note: [`CREATE PROCEDURE`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/ms187926.aspx): "Avoid the use of the **sp_** prefix when naming procedures. This prefix is used by SQL Server to designate system procedures."

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever, Okay! Thanks for your information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't want a temporary view.  You want an inline table-valued function:

```
create function udf_myview (
    @cola varchar(max)
   )
returns table
as
    return(select *
           from dbo.View_Test
           where cola = @cola
          );
```

You can then call this as:

```
select *
from dbo.udf_myview('XYZ');
```

Comment: If I want to pass multiple values to the @Cola because I want to show records from multiple tables. e.g `@Cola = 1,2,3`?

Comment: @Mak . . . That is a different question and should be asked as a question.  However, it is a relatively simple modification to the user-defined function.